# PHP search value in an array an return parent key

Tags: php

i try to search through an multi-Array to get the key back:

Array:

```
$types = array(
'ABD' => array('value'), 
'CDE' => array('from'), 
'EF' => array('array', 'array2', 'array30')
)
```

PHP

```
$key = array_search('array30', $types);
```

this should return "`EF`".

thanks for help.

Comment: `array_search(value,array,strict)` [ http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_search.asp ] visit link for more detail

Answer (score 2):

Try this. User a foreach loop and `in_array`

```
foreach($types as $key=>$data){ 
    if(in_array('array30',$data)){
        echo $key;      
    }

}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

get these elements have the array30 with array_filter and in_array.

```
var_dump(array_filter($types, function($v){in_array('array30', $v);}));
```

if you just want the key, use array_keys on the array_filter output.